# How did my stock got sold for the price that is higher than the 52 week (all-time) high?

Tags: stocks

On Friday (04-27-2018), I set limit price of $1,627 to sell my Amazon stock around 8 am. When I checked around 10:30 am, I had a notification (Robinhood app) that my order was executed for $1,653! Awesome! But later when I checked to see how high did the stock price had gone, to my surprise, the highest price was around $1638. Can anyone explain how the stock got sold for the price higher than that's on the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daily market data reflects trading during regular market hours.  AMZN opened at $1,634.01 and climbed to a high of $1,638.10 before trailing off and closing at $1,567.39

It was a different story during pre-market trading.  The high of almost $1,660 printed just before 9 AM and I would assume that's about when  your order was executed.  Check for time and sales on your execution confirm.

Here's a graph of AMZN for 4/26 to 4/27 that includes pre and after market trading:

http://thestockmarketwatch.com/stock/premarketQuote.aspx?stock=AMZN

Comment: Yes, my order was executed at 9:01 am. That explains, thank-you.

Comment: After reading your post again, I now realize that you set a limit price of $1,627 to sell your shares. From the graph I provided, you can see that AMZN hit that price around 8:30 and kept rising.  You got a fill 1/2 an hour later at $1,653.  That's a darn good fill but leads me to wonder how effective Robinhood is at placing  orders  in a timely fashion (you should have been executed sooner and at a lower price).  I'm sure there will be no complaints lodged against them by you ;->)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the point about market data reflecting trading activity during normal market hours, note that Robinhood may allow trading outside those hours. Per Robinhood's [Extended Trading Hours](https://support.robinhood.com/hc/en-us/articles/214681903-Extended-Trading-Hours) support page:

> With extended hours trading, you’ll be able to trade:
>
> - Pre-Market opens 30 minutes earlier starting at 9:00AM EST
> - After-Hours continues for 120 minutes (2 hours) until 6:00PM EST

So, traders with this service can execute trades as early as 9am. Since your limit price was met/exceeded at that time, you got the corresponding pre-market price (or quite close to it)